# For which values ​​of $a$ the function $f(x) = \max(x^2+2x,a) $ can be differentiate

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to find for what values of $a$ the function can be differentiate.
$$f(x) = \max(x^2+2x,a) $$
What I tried to do is:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2+2x &\text{if } a>\dots  \\
a& \text{if } a<\dots \end{cases} $$
the derivative of $x^2+2x$ is $2x+2$ and the critical point is $-\frac{1}{2}$

I need some hint how to continue.
Thanks!

Comment: Start with a sample value of $a$ and experiment. The second definition of $f$ is not same as first without more specifications on the value of $x$. You will see what I mean after you start your experimentation.

Comment: So if I understood you, $$\frac{-2^{+}_{-}\sqrt{4-4a}}{2}$$ will give me a state that the function have $x1$ and $x2$ but its depend in $a$, I saw that if $a<-1$ everything works find, but what is the explanation I give me $a>-1$?

Comment: What do you mean by the word "derived"? Are you taking derivatives?

Comment: yes, what is the correct word to demonstrate it? or you can edit the header by yourself.

Comment: If $a<-1$ then the line $y=a$ stays below graph of $y=x^2+2x$ and so you can differentiate $f$ with no problem. If $a>-1$ the the line cuts the graph of parabola at two pints. At those points the derivative does not exist because left and right derivatives are unequal.

Comment: ok I see that, how I write it? how I show that the derivatives are unequal? here its my problem.

Comment: Derive is not incorrect, but it's a bit ambiguous. "Differentiate" is a better term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rewrite this in your own words and supply the details.

$y=x^2+2x$ gives $y'=2x+2$, the critical minimum point is $(-1,-1)$. Hence if $a<-1$ then $\max\{x^2+2x, a\}=x^2+2x$ which is differentiable everywhere. If $a>-1$ then $x^2+2x=a$ gives $x={-1\pm \sqrt{1+a}}$. Between these point $f(x)=a$ and so $f'(x)=0$, Outside of these points $f'(x)=2x+2$. At the points of intersection $f'=\pm 2\sqrt{1+a}$ on the parabola side and zero on the side between the roots. Hence the left right derivatives differ at these points unless $a=-1$.

In short for $a<-1$ the function $f$ is differentiable everywhere.

For $a>-1$ it fails to be differetiable at two points, hence it is not differentiable.